# Preventing EF from including related entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a SQL Server database table that has a couple million records in it. I have an MVC site with a page to display data from this table, and I'm running into extensive performance issues.

Running a simple query like this takes about 25-30 seconds to return about two thousand rows:

```
_dbContext.Contracts
    .Where(c => c.VendorID == vendorId)
    .ToList();
```

When I run a query against the database, it only takes a couple seconds.

Turns out, EF is loading all the related entities for my `Contract`, so it's slowing down my query a ton.

In the debugger, the objects returned are of a strange type, not sure if that's an issue:

```
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Contract_3EF6BECBB56F2ADDDA6E0050AC82D03A4E993CEDF4FCA49244D3EE4005572C46
```

And the same with the related entities on my `Contract`:

```
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Vendor_4FB727808BD6E0BF3B25085B40F3F0B9B10EE4BD17D2A4C600214634F494DB66
```

The site is a bit old, it's MVC 3 with EF 4. I know on the current version of EF, I have to explicitly use `Include()` to get related entities, but here it seems to be included automatically.

I have an EDMX file, with a .tt file and entity classes under that, but I don't see anywhere that I can prevent my Courses from getting related objects.

Is there any way for me to do that?

Comment: Add `_dbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = _dbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;` before the query and you are done. For more info, search SO/documentation for "lazy loading".

Answer (score 1):

If your MVC controller is returning Entities to the view, the trap you're hitting is that the serializer is iterating over the entities returned and lazy-loading all related data. This is considerably worse than triggering an eager load because in the case of loading collections, this will fetch related entities/sets one parent at a time.

Say I fetch 100 Contracts and contracts contain a Vendor reference.

Eager loading I would use:

```
context.Contracts.Where(x => /* condition */).Include(x => x.Vendor).ToList();
```

which would compose 1 query loading all applicable contracts and their vendor details. However, if you let the serializer lazy load Vendors you get effectively the following:

```
context.Contracts.Where(x => /* condition */).ToList(); // gets applicable contracts...
// This happens behind the scenes for every single related entity touched while serializing...
context.Vendors.Where(x => x.VendorId == 1);
context.Vendors.Where(x => x.VendorId == 1);
// ... continue for each and every contract returned in the above list...
```

If Contract also has an Employee reference...

```
context.Employees.Where(x => x.EmployeeId == 16);
context.Employees.Where(x => x.EmployeeId == 12);
context.Employees.Where(x => x.EmployeeId == 11);
```

... and this continues for every related entity/collection in each contract and each related entity. It adds up, fast. You can see just how crazy it gets by hooking up a profiler to your server and kicking off a read. You expect 1 SQL, but then get hit with hundreds to thousands of calls.

The best way to avoid this is to simply not return entities from controllers, instead compose a view model with just the detail you want to display and use `.Select()` or Automapper's `.ProjectTo<ViewModel>()` to populate it from an EF query. This avoids falling into the trap of having a serializer touching lazy load properties, and also minimizes the payload sent to the client.

So if I wanted to display a list of contracts for a vendor and I only needed to display the Contract ID, the contract #, and a dollar figure:

```
[Serializable]
public class ContractSummaryViewModel
{
    public int ContractId { get; set; }
    public string ContractNumber { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

var contracts = _dbContext.Contracts
    .Where(c => c.VendorID == vendorId)
    .Select( c => new ContractSummaryViewModel
    {
        ContractId = c.ContractId,
        ContractNumber = c.ContractNumber,
        Amount = c.Amount
    })
    .ToList();
```

You can include details from related entities into the view model or compose related view models for key details, all without having to worry about using `.Include()` or tripping lazy loading. This composes a single SQL statement to load just the data you need, and passes just that back to the UI.  By streamlining the payload the performance can increase quite dramatically.